# "Arguments imply differing number of rows" Error after splliting data set into test and training sets

Tags: r, logistic-regression

The following code is me splitting the 'Weekly' data set into training and testing datasets. My training data set is supposed to contain years 1990-2008 while my testing data set spans 2009-2010. The Weekly data set is a dataset in R.

```
weekly.train = split(Weekly, Weekly$Year == 1990:2008)
weekly.test = split(Weekly, Weekly$Year == 2009:2010)
```

When I do a logistic regression model to the training set I get this error:

"Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE, : arguments imply differing number of rows: 1037, 52"

Here's my code for the regression:

```
mod.fit.lr<-glm(Direction ~ Lag1+Lag2+Lag3+Lag4+Lag5+Volume, data = weekly.train,family = binomial)
```

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

`split` returns a list of two groups (`TRUE` and `FALSE`), while you would want to have only one group (the target set). You can either extract the `TRUE` element or use indices explicitly:

```
i_test <- Weekly$Year %in% 2009:2019 

weekly.test <- Weekly[i_test, ]
weekly.train <- Weekly[!i_test, ]
```